# Win32Service - How to check if a Windows Service exists

Tags: php, winapi

I am using the Win32Service plugin for PHP and I can't see how to test if a service exists other than using win32_query_Service_status as this seems to return 1060 if it doesn't exist?

```
$arrServiceData = win32_query_Service_status($strServicename); 
return ($arrServiceData != 1060);
```

Does anybody have any better ideas on how to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see any problems testing it that way, save that you should do the comparison with `!==`, not `!=`, so you won't get surprises with conversions.

You can see return values on [win32 service constants page](http://www.php.net/manual/en/win32service.constants.errors.php), from there:

> WIN32_ERROR_SERVICE_DOES_NOT_EXIST    0x00000424  The specified service
>   does not exist as an installed service.

and `0x00000424` is `1060` in decimal, so that's the result if it does not exist.

Comment: Ok that's good to hear. I would rather use that constant enum value though and wasn't aware of !== but I will read up on it :-). Do you know how to actually reference that enum as it doesn't seem to know about it, i.e. ($arrServiceData !== WIN32_ERROR_SERVICE_DOES_NOT_EXIST) errors but ($arrServiceData !== 0x00000424); doesn't? Thanks

Comment: @Yos I would suspect they are constants only on winapi, and not predefined in php plugin. Not sure though. If else fails, you can define them yourself.